# Formateo de un EditText

Tags: android

Tengo un EditText que tiene este valor (ejemplo) 12.00 €, lo que quiero es pasarlo a una variable del tipo double pero solo 12.00

Lo he intentado asi:

```
double modcuota =  Double.valueOf(cuota.getText().toString());
```

Pero no me funciona

Comment: Hay un error es este es el bueno  double modcuota =  Double.parseDouble(cuota.getText().toString().trim());

Answer (score 0):

Para que el parseo sea exitoso necesitas que la cadena sea un Double válido, tu cadena tiene un símbolo de moneda por lo te está generando una excepción, para evitar esto es necesario eliminar el carácter "€", tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    String cuotaStr = cuota.getText().toString().trim();
    String validCuota = cuota.replace("€","");
    double modcuota =  Double.valueOf(validCuota);
```

Saludos.